# mediaplayer not able to play simultaneously multiple audio files

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have 5 tracks of vocals and intruments. I am trying to play them simultaneously but they are not syncing.

```
MediaPlayer mp1, mp2, mp3,mp4,mp5;

mp1.create(this,Uri1)
mp2.create(this,Uri1)
mp3.create(this,Uri1)
mp4.create(this,Uri1)
mp5.create(this,Uri1)

mp1.start();
mp2.start();
mp3.start();
mp4.start();
mp5.start();
```

All the media files are more than 10mb.

After 80s of playing the instruments are not syncing with the vocals.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Check out SoundPool: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html

Comment: will it play 10mb files also. Also I want to change the volume of each track. In mediaplayer, i was doing that with mp1.setvolume(0.5f).